# Dualboot - will reparation of Win10 cause my Ubuntu (GRUB) to fail booting?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, grub2, usb, windows-10

Not sure if the forum can help me with this:

Got a dualboot Win10 / Ubuntu (GRUB).

Took my smartphone from the usb-frontpanel, which caused my Win10 to crash fatally, bluescreen and shutdown. Now it wont even start in safe-mode.

Now after I tried all kind of troubleshoots, it appears I have to boot  and repair Win10 from USB-stick. (**edit:** this leads to blackscreen with blinking cursor)

I've read, this will cause Windows to overwrite files, that GRUB needs to boot. So even if I can repair my Win, Ubuntu will not boot anymore?
(**edit:** so far, Win still doesnt start in safe-mode, Ubuntu does start normal)

Now it appears, that I have to get all my documents/data from Ubuntu on an external drive,then try to repair or set back Win, open it to rescue my Win-files as well and finally do a fresh dualboot installation, like I did before. This sucks for couple reasons.

If anyone knows a workaround, can help me or give hints, I'd be more than happy. Please ask, if more info is needed.

thank you.

**edit:** here's the report of `$ boot-repair` , maybe this could be helpful?

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GNd9vDhmVc/

**edit2:** the folder `sys/firmware/efi` doesnt exist.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS installs? Windows is known in BIOS/MBR mode to update partition table and "forget" to include any Linux logical partitions. If UEFI, answer below applies, but you always have good backups, if making any major system changes.

Comment: UEFI, installed and ran `boot-repair` as told, but nothing changed. Still Win bluescreen and Ubuntu runs properly.

Comment: Both installs are in BIOS boot mode. Just be sure to have good backups. Also good idea to backup partition table to another device. Then if Windows does remove Linux partition, you can just restore partition table. Otherwise parted rescue or testdisk should find a missing partition. `sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > PT_sda.txt`

Comment: my linux files are saved already. But I cant boot from USB/DVD, even though my MB detects the USB specific as Sandisk. Was mounted correctly, does run install on another machine. Another option I didnt try yet is the set-back, which would kill all software installed, but keeps the files at least.... would be my last option, still I m not sure if it would fail too.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is likely that your GRUB will be gone after repairing Windows. BUT you do not have to reinstall Ubuntu, you can simply reinstall GRUB. This problem can also happen on certain Windows updates which override the bootloader.
This [Article](https://techwiser.com/fix-grub-after-windows-10-upgrade/) about GRUB and how to fix might help you.

Comment: the article's troubleshoots both didnt work for me.